# How to store laravel passport token on browser and how and when to send refresh token

Tags: javascript, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel passport to generate access token and refresh token. 
How and when to check if token is expired and how to request for new token?

Comment: why not at page load?

Comment: i am using ajax

Comment: where do you store the token?

Comment: well i am storing both access token and refresh token in cookies

Comment: so you can do this at page load with javascript

Comment: how and when to check if token is expired and how to request for new token?

Comment: at page load man, when the user navigates to another page you check if the cookie expired if it has expired you trigger the token refresh

Comment: Is it good to store access token and refresh token at same place ??? (cookie)

Comment: from what i know the access token should be stored in a db/server, i am not to familiar with oauth

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JavaScript application, you should probably use the OAuth2 Implicit flow which gives you an access token and its expiration time. So don't use the Autorization Code Grant flow which works with refresh tokens - it requires a client secret which you cannot keep safe in a browser.

When you get an access token, schedule its refresh using `window.setTimeout()`. You could refresh it without user interaction using the request parameter `prompt=none` (see [OpenID Connect RFC](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html)). If the token gets invalidated before its regular timeout, you will get an "HTTP 401 Unauthorized" response from a backend. In such case, check the token validity and get a new one if necessary.

It's not a good idea to have the access token as a cookie, because it gets attached to every request (with the same domain, port and possibly path), which may be a security problem. Keep it in `sessionStorage`.

Comment: for refresh token it requires client secret. but i have kept client secret on proxy server.